# Advice to un-stick a bathroom sink waste plug which is stuck down please

Tags: bathroom, sink

My bathroom sink (handbasin) has a pop-up waste, similar to the one shown here:[image]

However it has become STUCK in the down position, totally blocking the sink. A picture is here:

This means I can not use my bathroom sink. There is nowhere to grip it.

Short of drilling it out - what advice would you suggest?

[image]

Comment: Should be able to undo the whole drain from below, no drilling necessary.

Comment: A bit of confusion here about terminology (which will determine which answer is correct). When it was working properly, what would you actually do to open/close the drain?

Comment: maybe you are not pressing it down hard enough to release it... otherwise, try using a small suction cup to pull it up or to unscrew it ... small suction cups are used for hanging decorations on glass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to everyone who answered this!

I ultimately solved it myself with the help of the following video:
https://youtu.be/ZWlq_fWRrzI

I used a rubber glove to give me enough traction on the thumb to unscrew the cap - which was then raised flush with the surrounding metal.

I then used dental floss to slowly and carefully catch the waste cap - which I was then able to lift out.

The brass pin below (onto which the cap screwed) was stuck down tight, and needed some WD40 and a pair of pliers to fix.

Anyway - thank you to all the suggestions here :)

Answer (score 2):

I would disassemble the trap below the drain, and if necessary remove the tailpiece, and push it up with something like a screwdriver

Answer (score 2):

I have had just that happen to me. This is what I did: Spray around the edges with WD-40. Let it sit for 5-10 min. then press it hard and release multiple times. When it finally pops up unscrew the pop-up from the sink drain and WD-40 the spring and shaft. When you screw it back in don't screw it down so far that it is recessed as far as it is now.
If none of that works you have no choice but to dissemble the drain.

Comment: If I recollect correctly, WD-40 will eventually evaporate away. A follow-up oil or grease suitable for a drain applied to the moving parts might be good.

Answer (score 1):

It worked, I sprayed WD40 on it and waited 10 minutes.Then I used a large plastic nail and gently tapped it with a hammer then pressed firmly and the plug came up. I then unscrewed the plug and gave the thread a brush with a nail brush and sprayed with WD40. I lost my husband a few years ago and try to fix problems myself if possible so thank you for your guidance

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/162849)

Comment: That answer has already been given.

Answer (score 1):

There are silicone suction cups that would fit on this drain that can allow a very stong upward pull. Stick this suction cup onto the plug, push down forcefully and pull up forcefully.

I would keep one of these handy if you have this type of drain plug. A couple of years ago I installed one of these pop-up drain plugs in a bathroom lavatory in my house, but we have have no trouble with it. I don't have a silicone suction cup right now, but I now have that on my list.